# Access Windows guest via remote desktop connection through vmplayer

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vmware-player

I have a vmplayer image of a Windows XP Pro guest and would like to be able to access it via a remote desktop client `rdesktop` in a Slackware Linux host.

Is this possible? Or do I really need to use the paid VMWare Workstation?

I've run `vmware-netcfg` but didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: @CanadianLuke I don't know whether it's relevant, but it's Windows XP. The problem is letting vmplayer allow the connection to the guest.

Comment: @CanadianLuke XP Pro

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) from another station in your network to access the *Virtual Operating System* (not the VM) by using built in tools in Windows XP Pro (which support will end in April). Note that the difference is that Remote Desktop to the VM will give you access to the VM's BIOS, and the ability to watch the Startup animation before the Windows GUI loads. Accessing the *Virtual Operating System* through remote desktop will make it feel like a normal Windows XP system that you remote desktop with.

1. As an Administrator, make sure you have a password on your account
2. Click Start-> Right-click on My Computer and click Properties
3. Click the Remote tab
4. Ensure Remote Desktop Connections are allowed to be received.

On your VM, make sure you have Bridged-mode Networking set up. This will make Windows XP believe it's plugged into the same switch/router as your host computer, and it will get an IP address in the same range. Note what it is.

On your computer that you want to connect to it with, run your remote desktop program, and type in the new IP address of the XP VM to connect.